can I use the taskquery or to do a in query in flowable 7
I am using flowable 7 as the workflow engine, now I need to use multiple process id to to a in query. From the flowable source I did not found the processdefinitionIdIn function, just have this query:
taskService.createTaskQuery().processDefinitionId(processInstanceId);

could I use this way to do a in query to fond task from multiple process definition id?
taskService.createTaskQuery().processDefinitionId(processDefinitionId1).or().processDefinitionId(processDefinitionId2)

is that a good practice?

This won't return tasks for either of the process instances, since you need to use .or() always together with .endOr(). Between those you can then have the different methods to be called which should be combined with an or, e.g.:
taskService.createTaskQuery()
      .or()
      .processDefinitionId(processDefinitionId1)
      .processInstanceId(processInstanceId)
      .endOr()
      .list()

However, when you call now .processDefinitionId(...) twice inside the .or(), it will overwrite the previous process definition id and only find the tasks to last process definitions.
In case you are searching for the same process in different versions, I would suggest to use the .processDefinitionKey(...).
If you are searching within the same deployment and multiple process definitions, you can consider combining the .processDefinitionKeyIn(...) with the .deploymentId(...).
